# Database replication between xampp MySQL database and database on my website server

Tags: php, database, mysql

I need to keep my database on xampp phphmyadmin and the live database on the live server synchronized.

Here the situation is changes will be made on both the xampp local database on PC and the live database. And the weird situation is the local PC will be offline most of the time with no internet connection. But it need to sync once the internet connection comes back and so when the connection is up both the live and PC database must become the same.

So local changes must go to live and live must come to local. Is there any way I can attain this. Using MySQL or php?

Comment: given the local pc is offline, then no, you can't use any buit-in replication items in mysql. you'll have to do something externally, e.g. a job that triggers when the network comes up and push updates back and forth.

Comment: Unless your online server is some kind of staging area i would suggest you are -very- careful when replicating to a live server.

Comment: @MarcB, Thanks for the answer. I am good in php but not in mysql replication. Using php how can I get the difference in database and sync. Also what if both database has records with the same id when the internet comes back.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds dangerous to me. I would suggest just having updates go from live to local using mysql replication and make changes to live only. It doesn't matter if your local machine is off, mysql replication will kick in when it starts back up, from where it left off.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But Is it possible to do manually using php. eg can I get all the mysql queries executed after the internet went offline?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set your local server to use your remote servers database?

Comment: Thansk for the answer. But if the internet go down will it be possible to access the remote server database and make changes. The requirement here is the client is in a place where there is no internet connection most of the time. so the client needs to use it from his local server and when internet comes up sync with the live database. But other users are using live database so a conflict between primary key id will be an issue.

Comment: What your trying to do is bad. Lets say he makes changes locally but then decides to upload everything to the live server. If all of the changes get overwritten then you have a chance of loosing live data that has been submitted between the time he pulled the data and the time he uploaded the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this question. Hope this will be useful to someone whose having the same problem.

We can adjust the auto increment(value incremented in each increment and the offset)

More details refer.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/ja/replication-auto-increment.html